# System Messages:Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, price, stock

1- How do I deal with this problem

System messages

One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.

[image]

Comment: refer this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html please try before you post something here. Magento advises it already

Answer (score 1):

You have to just run indexer command using command line,

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

After run this command your indexer are **status are ready**.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't have access to command line (terminal) you can run reindex through Admin panel under `System->Index Management` by selecting checkbox for the ones that say **Reindex Required**, from **Actions** dropdown select **Update on Save** and click **Submit** button.

Please note reindexing can take a while depending on how much data you have in your website so if you have alot of products then it's advisable to run one by one indexer.